# PHP imagick or any other tool, how to detect if there is visible transparency on gifs files

Tags: php, transparency, gif, imagick, animated-gif

I am working on a service that can do conversions from gif to mp4 files (with `ffmpeg`).

My problem is some of the gifs have **visible** transparent areas which end up as white color when I convert them to mp4 video.
To avoid that problem I am trying detect if a gif has **visible** transparent areas so I will avoid converting them to mp4.

I tried to use `getImageAlphaChannel()` function from imagick.

```
   if ($imagick->getImageAlphaChannel()) {
      echo 'transparent image';
   } else {
      echo 'not transparent image';   
   }
```

This function works correctly reports transparent for images like below; which has obvious visible transparent areas.

[image: transparent gif 1]

But it also reports transparent for images like below;

[image: false transparent gif 1]

[image: false transparent gif 2]

This result is probably correct for imagick , probably above images are  transparent , but according to my eyes there are no **visible** transparent areas.

My question is how can I correctly identify, if a gif file that has **visible** transparent areas or it is even possible with imagick or any other tool ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP imagick detect transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742718/php-imagick-detect-transparency)

Comment: Dump the output of `$imagick->getImageAlphaChannel()`. Do you get an other values besides 0 or 1? If so, you might need to check the colour space. Here's an article that kind of explains what I'm talking about https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/473/how-to-check-if-an-image-has-transparency-using-imagick-in-php

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit thank you for the help , it is my mistake not to emphasize enough **visible** keyword. I read the question you sent ,before sending this question,but unfortunately it does not help me since I am trying to detect not just transparency also for visible transparency, which is harder I believe.

Comment: @BrettGregson thanks for the help, I also read the article you sent, before asking that question,  but it didn't make a difference , same results for me. I don't get any value other than 0 or 1. I was using that code before ; 

```if($image->getImageAlphaChannel() == Imagick::COLORSPACE_UNDEFINED){
    echo "The image has no transparency :(";
}else{
    echo "The image has transparency !";
}```

But it didn't make a difference , so I have returned the code that I sent in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Imagick::getImageChannelRange` to evaluate the min/max of values used by a specific color channel.

```php
$alphaRange = $imagick->getImageChannelRange(Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

You can then check if there is any transparency with...

```php
$hasTransparency = $alphaRange['minima'] < $alphaRange['maxima'];
```

- If the channel is defined, and has any transparent areas across any frame, then `maxima` will always be greater then `minima`.
- If the channel is NOT defined, then `minima` will be `Inf` placeholder, and `maxima` will be `-Inf` placeholder, so the above check will still work.
- If the whole image has a consistent alpha-value (i.e. full transparency, or no data variation), this solution would not work. A fallback check could be something like... `minima == maxima AND minima > 0`

Another great benefit from evaluating ranges is that you can check the distance between the two min/max values against a threshold, so a "little semi-transparency" can be identified & isolated.

```php
$threshold = $imagick->getQuantum() * 0.1; // < 10% is okay.
$hasTransparency = $alphaRange['minima'] < $alphaRange['maxima']
                 && ($alphaRange['maxima'] - $alphaRange['minima']) < $threshold;
```

Comment: Hey @emcconville, thanks for helping me , 
I am totally newbie for imagick, please fix me if I am saying nonsense.
 gif but afaik gif does not support alpha transparency only index transparency, so

Comment: When I execute and collect values of `$imagick->getImageChannelRange(Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);` I see the same numbers for many transparent and non-transparent gifs , which does not help me , I get the same results for those gifs